# How to print the logs of all ansible tasks of a playbook in RFC5424 format?

Tags: ansible-2.x

It is required to print the logs of all ansible tasks in a playbook in RFC5424 format. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible output is controlled by the callback plugins. There is [a number of built-in ones](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html), including [`syslog_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/syslog_json_callback.html), [`unixy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/unixy_callback.html#ansible-collections-community-general-unixy-callback) or even [`diy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html#ansible-collections-community-general-diy-callback) that might help.

If none of the built-in plugins fits your requirements, you can always use a custom one (either found in some collection, or written by yourself).

Comment: Is there also a way to print Ansible logs to a file in RFC5424 format ?